# angular 2 beta ie 10 "Potentially unhandled rejection [3] SyntaxError: Expected"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, typescript, angular

This is an Angular 2 Beta question.  I am specifically being general at first in the hope that this is a known error and I just missed something in all my searching.  When Angular 2 Beta.0 came out i got a very simple module running in my application using IE10.  It basically printed something like "My first module".

When Angular 2 Beta.1 came out I tried the running the same code and got the following error.  This happens in Angular2 2.0.0-beta.2 & angular2 2.0.0-beta.3 also:

```
    EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: Expected ';'
```

STACKTRACE:

```
SyntaxError: Expected ';'
   at evalExpression (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:452:5)
   at _createViewFactoryRuntime (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24190:9)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24144:13)
   at run (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1243:14)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:13408:15)
   at zoneBoundFn (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1220:14)
   at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:468:10)
   at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:480:10)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1028:14)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:123:10)
```

-----async gap-----

```
Error
   at _getStacktraceWithCaughtError (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2240:10)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2285:14)
   at bind (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1218:10)
   at bindArguments (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1401:14)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1413:18)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24142:11)
   at run (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1243:14)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:13408:15)
   at zoneBoundFn (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1220:14)
   at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:468:10)
```

-----async gap-----

```
Error
   at _getStacktraceWithCaughtError (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2240:10)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2285:14)
   at bind (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1218:10)
   at bindArguments (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1401:14)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1413:18)
   at _compileComponentRuntime (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24131:9)
   at _compileNestedComponentRuntime (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24159:7)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24140:13)
   at forEach (.../js/angular/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js:10:16871)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24139:11)
```

-----async gap-----

```
Error
   at _getStacktraceWithCaughtError (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2240:10)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2285:14)
   at bind (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1218:10)
   at bindArguments (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1401:14)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1413:18)
   at _compileComponentRuntime (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24131:9)
   at compileHostComponentRuntime (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24085:9)
   at compileInHost (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24436:7)
   at loadAsRoot (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12326:7)
   at useFactory (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12424:9)
```

-----async gap-----

```
Error
   at _getStacktraceWithCaughtError (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2240:10)
   at Anonymous function (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:2285:14)
   at _createInnerZone (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:13396:7)
   at NgZone (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:13262:9)
   at createNgZone (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12446:5)
   at application (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:12521:7)
   at bootstrap (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:24631:5)
   at main (Unknown script code:9:9)
   at Anonymous function (.../communicationReport.do?dispatch=showCommunicationCounts&wsession=new&entityId=10009ndlgxmw:34:14)
   at run (.../js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:1243:14)
```

The files I am loading (same for Angular 2 Beta.0, Angular 2 Beta.1, Angular 2 Beta.2) are:

```
<script src="js/angular/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

<script src="js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

Update: My boot.ts looks like:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import {CountsComponent} from './counts.component';
export function main() {

    bootstrap( CountsComponent );

}
```

My counts.component.ts file looks like:

```
  import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'counts',
    template: '<h1>Landing Page1</h1>'
})
export class CountsComponent { }
```

The initial html looks like

```
    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript', 
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
        packages: {'modules/counts': {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'}} 
      });
      System.import('modules/counts/boot')
            .then(function( bootstrap ) {
                bootstrap.main();
            }, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body class="counts">
    <counts>Loading 1...</counts>
  </body>
```

Is this a known problem?  Does it have a fix?  Do you need more info?

Comment: What does your template look like that it is loading?

Comment: updated original with more info.

Comment: updated for angular2 2.0.0-beta.3

Comment: FYI: i tried the quick start from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html and got the same error.  BTW, i had to install tsd in order to get zone to install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. Found a quick fix in plunker. Insert following code before es6-shim.min.js script in plunker example:

```
<script>
    if (!Function.name) {
        Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "name", {
            get: function () {
              var result = this.toString();
                var results = /function (.{1,})\(/.exec(this.toString());
                return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : result;
            }

        });     
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident") != -1) {
        console.warn("QUICK FIX NAME ON FUNCTION IS OBSOLETE.");
    }
</script>
```

This quick fix does not resolve all the problems with angular 2 and IE.
Hope this is some help...

Comment: The following solution I concoct seems to resolve all the problems I had with mine angular 2 project running in IE. First I needed systemjs version 0.19.22. Second move the code above after loading of angular2-polyfills.js script instead of after the loading of es6-shim.min.js

Comment: ...I mean instead of **before** the loading of es6-shim.min.js

Comment: Tom, I was able to get it to work with the A2 Quickstart after I brought in systemjs, which was not required by the quickstart.  Can you explain a little bit about what is wrong?  It looks like JS Function did not have name property?  Is this a feature of IE?

Comment: The [Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) property is a Javascript ECMAScript 2015 standard not yet supported by IE 11. I suspect it will be resolved, in the near future, by one of the polyfills scripts, angularjs2 or systemjs. Meanwhile I want to be able to test IE and angular 2 so I made this quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved in angular version 2.0.0-beta.8 by including:

angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_ie.js

Quick fix no longer needed.