# Angular2 RC1 with IE10 and 9, Unhandled Promise rejection: SyntaxError: Expected '/'

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

The angular solution works great on IE11+ but with IE10 and 9, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: SyntaxError: Expected '/' 
    at Anonymous function (eval code:13:1) 
    at Anonymous function (eval code:1:31) 
    at eval code (eval code:1:2) 
    Evaluating /application_ref.js 
    Evaluating /index.js 
    Error loading ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: SyntaxError: Expected '/' 
    at Anonymous function (eval code:13:1) 
    at Anonymous function (eval code:1:31) 
    at eval code (eval code:1:2) 
    Evaluating http://localhost:1000/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.js 
    Evaluating http://localhost:1000/node_modules/@angular/core/index.js 
    Error loading http://localhost:1000/Scripts/app.js ...
```

There's a compatibility issue with IE10 and i just can't see what could be causing it. Tried using [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com) in the hope of adding more comprehensive support for ES5 and ES6 but no luck.

Even worse, if i use [SystemJS-Builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder) to create a self executing bundle (SFX), then it works great in both IE10 and 9 and issue goes away. Any help is appreciated.

It's a very similar issue to this: [angular 2 beta ie 10 "Potentially unhandled rejection [3] SyntaxError: Expected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158977/angular-2-beta-ie-10-potentially-unhandled-rejection-3-syntaxerror-expected)